# Wocommerce Update Cart Button Not Updating Cart

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am having problem updating the cart when i click the update cart button nothing happens. The day i changed the cart.php file this started to happen i changed the table with divs it works fine with old table code and classes but with new code it does not works well.

Below is the code for old and new code with js files.

This is the link for new cart.php file sorry i could not post code because it had formating errors that i could not solved.

https://shop.mmstore.be/newcart.txt

This is the link for old cart.php file i cannot post the code due to formating errors which i could not solve.

https://shop.mmstore.be/oldcart.txt

This is the link  for wocommerce cart.js file due to words limit i had to post the code from the link.

https://shop.mmstore.be/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/cart.js

Please tell me what is going on wrong.

Thanks

I tried to make ajax call but it is not working with the new code with old code the ajax calls goes out well.